# Why am I not able to see the result in XML format?

Tags: php, rest, curl, yahoo-api

I'm trying to use Yahoo's content analysis, which seems really easy to use from [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/content/V2/contentAnalysis.html)

But whenever I execute my code, I get the following output, as it is:

```
Italian sculptors the Virgin Mary painters http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Painting http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Still_life http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Avant-garde http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/In_the_Sky http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Potato 1
```

What I want is to see an XML document structured with the XML tags just like the way it appears when you click [this](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20contentanalysis.analyze%20where%20text=%27Italian%20sculptors%20and%20painters%20of%20the%20renaissance%20favored%20the%20Virgin%20Mary%20for%20inspiration%27;) link

Also, the source code (from the browser.. the right click>view source thing) of what I'm seeing as the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2012-11-24T05:54:55Z" yahoo:lang="en-US"><results><entities xmlns="urn:yahoo:cap">
    <entity score="0.784327">
      <text end="16" endchar="16" start="0" startchar="0">Italian sculptors</text>
    </entity>
    <entity score="0.78097">
      <text end="72" endchar="72" start="58" startchar="58">the Virgin Mary</text>
    </entity>
    <entity score="0.509566">
      <text end="29" endchar="29" start="22" startchar="22">painters</text>
      <wiki_url>http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Painting</wiki_url>
      <related_entities>
        <wikipedia>
          <wiki_url>http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop</wiki_url>
          <wiki_url>http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Still_life</wiki_url>
          <wiki_url>http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Avant-garde</wiki_url>
          <wiki_url>http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/In_the_Sky</wiki_url>
          <wiki_url>http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Potato</wiki_url>
        </wikipedia>
      </related_entities>
    </entity>
  </entities></results></query><!-- total: 191 -->
<!-- engine6.yql.ac4.yahoo.com -->
1
```

Following is my code :

```
<?php
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "q=select * from contentanalysis.analyze where text='Italian sculptors and painters of the renaissance favored the Virgin Mary for inspiration';");
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
$op=curl_exec ($c);
curl_close ($c); 
echo $op;
?>
```

Comment: I've added a solution to your stray string problem in an edit to my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is how XML is displayed in the browser when the header being sent is `Content-type:  text/html`. The demo example you link to that shows formatted XML uses some special formatting to get it looking like that. You need to set the header to be text/xml like `header('Content-type: text/xml');` and then the output should display formatted.

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $op;
```

You can also output your content like so:

```
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlentities($op);
echo '</pre>';
```

---

The above explains why XML shows up unformatted in the browser and demonstrates how to fix that. The OP's main problem is that his XML is malformed due to that stray string at the the end of the output. The following deals with that:

```
$r = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
$p = "q=select * from contentanalysis.analyze where text='Italian sculptors and painters of the renaissance favored the Virgin Mary for inspiration'"; 

$c = curl_init($r);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$op = curl_exec ($c);
curl_close ($c); 

if (!($xml = strstr($op, '<?xml'))) {
    $xml = null;
}

header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $xml;
```

Comment: So do you know why am I also getting the extra '1' at the end of the entire XML data?

Comment: The first method is having trouble because of that stray "1"... that makes the xml invalid. What do you get with the second method I suggested?

Comment: Yeah the second one works perfect. But just to see what was wrong, I edited my code to match yours here http://pastie.org/5426972 and I still can't get it working. I see the error : This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error....
What am I doing wrong? I just skipped the if(!$xml... part from your code, which should be fine as long as the curl_exe() method isn't returning something that doesn't start with <?xml right?

Comment: Sorry, found out the problem. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

If you seen that result in a browser. You should just do view source. That will show everything including tags. As brousr would not display tags, just content.

Comment: I know. I have added the view source content to the question too if you see :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used the `header` method to specify the `Content-Type` HTTP header. Consequently, PHP is outputting its default Content-Type of `text/html` and the browser is treating the XML markup as invalid HTML.

Output the correct content-type for your data.

```
header("Content-Type: application/xml");
```

Comment: Even when I add that, I get the following error:
http://pastebin.com/BTjHwABp. And this is when I add your line BEFORE I echo the output.